# GWT event handling. Needs to block the event till form submit finish

Tags: gwt, gxt

I'm developing a wizard by using GWT. In the Wizard first page i have a form component to upload the file. In the wizard panel i have the next button when i press the next button the validation method will be triggered if the validation is passed then i'm calling the form.submit(); but before form.submit() handler starts the functionality the validation methods completes it. After it completes the validation method only the form submit it's really taking part. How can i controll this event behavior, when i submit the form using form.submit() the remaining actions has to wait till this form returns to it's handler.

Advance Thanks.

Comment: Could you rephrase the question ? If I understand you well you want to wait for the validation to complete before doing the submit. Is that so ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `FormPanel`:

```
FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
```

You can add a handler:

```
form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {

    public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        // TODO: Do the next step in the wizard
        // Use event.getResults() to get the text of the response
    }
});
```

Comment: It's fine. but you misunderstood the question. The pbm is some other event is firing the form.submit() function. I want the function one has to wait till the submit() is finished the work.. How could the above code will work on that scenario??

Comment: It doesn't matter which event fires form.submit(), the submit-complete handler will still fire.

Comment: The problem here is, The function which triggered the form.submit() has to be wait till the forms onsubmitcomplete listener function completes. Hope you understood now..

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for synchronous code. Javascript in the browser is a world of asynchronous callbacks. The method that submits the form cannot wait like that. You have to think differently about how you write the code: make the wizard steps run via a set of callback methods, not one single method.

Comment: Yes. I can understand the problem. If i want to change then i have to change mostly everything in my code. It takes a lot of changes, i thought like it may have some other way to handle it. Any how thanks for your help..

Comment: No problem. It takes a bit of getting used to, but it actually produces quite nice code (more decoupled).

Answer (score 0):

Write a boolean which you'll set to true once the validation is complete. Then start a timer that waits on that boolean. But consider using events and callbacks for repeated use. Using timer will make your code messy if you overuse them.

```
@UiHandler("submit")
protected void onSubmit() {
    validated=false;
    validate();
    Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedDelay(new RepeatingCommand() {
        public boolean execute() {
            if (validated) {
               if (validationSucceeded()) {
                   submit();
               }
               return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }, 250);
}

private boolean validated = false;

private void validate() {
    // do validation
    validated=true;
}
```